# Can't find file tgtermes (luatex)

Tags: tex-core, tex-gyre-math

I'm trying to build [tyscheme](https://github.com/ds26gte/tyscheme.git), which is a TeX (*not* LaTeX) document. The README file directs me to run a sequence of commands, the first one is `luatex index`, which fails as it can't find file `tgtermes` to `\include`. A search directs me to the TeX-Gyre fonts, which I do have installed (there is a `tgtermes.sty` package for LaTeX here).

Local environment is TeXlive on Fedora 33.

Comment: the tex2page github which is linked from the one you mention contains a tgtermes.tex. But it view of the age of the various files I wouldn't bet on it that this still compiles.

Answer (score 1):

As Ulrike Fischer comments, there is a `tgtermes.tex`file in the (referenced) `tex2page` package (of the same author, so it should work). Installed that one in my home's `texmf` tree.

Next came `plainsection.tex` (again from `tex2page`) and I had to grab `miniltx` directly from CTAN.

Finally, you need to run `mpost numint` first, to create the required image.

Phew!